# for loop condition issue in c++?

Tags: c++

I m working with a pattern program but facing one issue my condition is false then the condition is run?

Pattern Programme:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i,j,k,n;

    std::cout << "Enter Number:" ;
    cin>>n;

    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)    //row 
    {
        //first time condition  false 1(k value)<1(i value) not execute first time this is ok
        //second time condition false 2(k value)<2(i value) why this condition run when condition is false????

        for(int k=1;k<i;k++) //space 
        {
            cout << " ";
        }

        for(int j=i;j<=n;j++)  //column
        {
                std::cout << "*" ;
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

execute of program:

ex: user enter 3

first time excite condition properly :

**now i=1 and k=1**

```
  for(int i=1;1<=3;i++)    //row 
   {
        for(int k=1;1<1;k++) //space  //1<1 false  ok.
        {
           cout << " ";
        }
```

Issue with second-time condition:

**now i=2 and k=2**

```
  for(int i=1;2<=3;i++)    //row 
   {
        for(int k=1;2<2;k++) //space  //2<2 false  Not Ok problem is here why these condition is run
        {
           cout << " ";
        }
```

Link Programme:https://onlinegdb.com/Hk9DHuwvL

Comment: What is the issue? What output are you expecting?

Comment: @DaniloIvanovic why space loop is one-time run that is my issue?? even I write k++

Answer (score 2):

when `i=2 and k=2`, your explanation is wrong, the right one is:

When `i=2`, inner code of `i` loop is:

```
    for(int k=1;k<2;k++) //space, loops one time 
    {
        cout << " ";
    }

    for(int j=2;j<=3;j++)  //column, loops two times
    {
            std::cout << "*" ;
    }
    cout << "\n";
```

Comment: why space loop is run one time that is my issue?? even I write k++

Comment: The space loop runs one time because `i == 2`. Look at the loop `for(int k=1;k<i;k++)`. If `i == 2` then the loop runs one time. How many times were you expecting it to run?

Comment: problem is that second time i=2 this is right but also k=2 but here k=1 that is the reason still i does solve this thing a

Comment: I hope my question is understood to you

Comment: `i=2 this is right but also k=2`  **That is wrong**, k = 1 not 2

Comment: @dipsvirag May I suggest you to write values of the variables in each loop? You will see, because it seems that you have problem with the way loops work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your loop

```
for (int k=1;k<i;k++)
{
    cout << " ";
}
```

This loop starts at `1` and goes up to but not including `i`. So it runs `i - 1` times. If `i == 1` then it runs zero times, if `i == 2` then it runs one time, if `i == 3` then it runs two times, if `i == 4` then it runs three times, etc. etc.

You seem to think the the number of times it has run before makes a difference to how many times it runs next, but that is not true. The loop **starts again** each time it is run.

Comment: you mean again k value is reset 1 when increasing 2 and now again k value is reset  1 when increased 3 ?

Comment: @dipsvirag Yes, k is reset each time the loop runs.

Comment: now my confusion is clearly that is the my doubt  thanks john